# Can the cause for cURL error "Failed to connect to host" (7) ever be on the requesting client side?

Tags: curl, networking

I am trying to connect to a third-party service using cURL. They had to enable two of my machines with two different IPs to allow access to their servers. Request from one machine works. Requests from the other machine results in

```
curl  x.x.x.x:xxxx --verbose
* About to connect() to x.x.x.x port xxxx (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to x.x.x.x:xxxx; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to x.x.x.x:xxxx; Connection refused
```

Contacting other ips with cURL works as expected.

Is is possible that the problem is on my client side? If so, what could it be?
Or must the cause be on their server side?

Comment: sure it can be on the client side, if you have a firewall on your local machine that blocks access to that ip. add `-v`, then check what do you get in stderr?

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks. I updated the question with the ouput of the verbose request. There is not really more information.

Comment: Not enough information are provided unfortunately. Is there a firewall in your network? If yes check with the team if the 2nd IP is authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**
The outbound port was blocked on the firewall of the client side.

So today I learned that the same port is actually used on both sides of the request. I was not aware of that.